# pg_stat_activity entries with no corresponding process on the client

Tags: postgresql, pg-stat-activity

If I see an entry in pg_stat_activity for a client_addr:client_port combination where there is no process bound to that port on the indicated client, what does that mean?  Just that the client process exited before the query completed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably correct that this simply means that the client process exited.  If it exits without cleaning up the connection while its back-end server process is working on a query, then the server process will not notice until it tries to send a message to the client and finds that no one is there.

If it takes a long time to return a tuple (because it has to sort or aggregate before it sends the first one, for example) then the server process can be a dead man walking for a long time.

There was discussion about fixing this, but finding a way to do it in a performant and cross-platform way is not easy.

Comment: Can a server process stay alive waiting on a lock even when the client process has exited?

Comment: Yes.  If you need to kill a `psql` session while it is waiting on a lock, do it with `SIGINT` or by hitting Ctrl-C from the tty.  Don't kill it with `SIGTERM` or `SIGKILL`.  With the first method, `psql` sends a cancel message to its server so it knows to cancel the lock wait.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say given the lack of specifics here, but most likely it's just timing differences - the backend exited moments after you looked at `pg_stat_activity` and before you looked at `ps` or `netstat` or whatever you were using to look at it at the OS level.

`pg_stat_activity` gets cleaned up when the postmaster notices the child process exiting, so if the postmaster is extremely busy it might take a moment after the backend actually exits. However, you'd usually see a short-lived "zombie" process still there until the postmaster notices it. It may or may not retain its socket.